# make \mycommand\mycommand do something different than \mycommand twice

Tags: macros

Is there any way we can define a command `\mycommand` so that it does one thing when used in isolation and another thing when used in succession?

I additionally want to allow that `\mycommand' can have (optional) arguments.

Comment: How about you show all your use cases in a minimal example so the community can have something to play with. Can you do that?

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: you can, see `\hline\hline` but it's not to be recommended in most cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this is to use `\NewDocumentCommand` with the `t`-argument type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand { t{\mycommand} O{} }
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{Duplicated}{Single} variant.
    Optional argument: #2.%
  }

\begin{document}
\mycommand[abc]

\mycommand\mycommand[def]
\end{document}
```

[image]